# Call stored procedure with string variable inside IN condition

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi have below SP which is running fine for the single value for example PARMPROFILES=wervbcjjlj

```
create or replace procedure OneView_Rpt_Get_Profile(PARMPROFILES       varchar2,
                                                 out_curResults OUT sys_refcursor) is
begin


OPEN out_curResults FOR
  select  
 upper(concat(concat(first_name, ' '), last_name)) User_Name,
         ul.user_id as User_ID,
         ul.Email_Id as EmailAddress,
         p.profile_name as profilename,
         upper(concat(concat(PW.OWNER_FIRST_NAME, ' '), PW.OWNER_LAST_NAME)) as OwnerName,
        PU.ADDED_DATE 
    from User_List UL
    join Profile_User PU on UL.USER_KEY = PU.USER_KEY
    join Profile_Owner PW on PW.PROFILE_KEY = PU.PROFILE_KEY and PW.ACTIVE='Y'
    join Profile p on p.profile_key= pu.profile_key       
   where 1=1
     AND UL.GU_ID IS NOT NULL
      and ul.active_flag = 'Y'
      and p.profile_name in (PARMPROFILES  );


end OneView_Rpt_Get_Profile;
```

but i want to pass multiple values in PARMPROFILES . where i run only simple query with multiple value its run fine

```
     select  
 upper(concat(concat(first_name, ' '), last_name)) User_Name,
         ul.user_id as User_ID,
         ul.Email_Id as EmailAddress,
         p.profile_name as profilename,
         upper(concat(concat(PW.OWNER_FIRST_NAME, ' '), PW.OWNER_LAST_NAME)) as OwnerName,
        PU.ADDED_DATE 
    from User_List UL
    join Profile_User PU on UL.USER_KEY = PU.USER_KEY
    join Profile_Owner PW on PW.PROFILE_KEY = PU.PROFILE_KEY and PW.ACTIVE='Y'
    join Profile p on p.profile_key= pu.profile_key       
   where 1=1
     AND UL.GU_ID IS NOT NULL
      and ul.active_flag = 'Y'
      and p.profile_name in ('wervbcjjlj','test_shub_prt'  )
```

Not sure how to pass multiple value in SP. Please Advice !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split entered comma-separated values into rows (lines #9 - 11) and use it as a subquery.

This is an example with a function (for simplicity):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_in in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7    select empno, ename, job, sal
  8    from emp
  9    where job in (select regexp_substr(par_in, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 10                  from dual
 11                  connect by level <= regexp_count(par_in, ',') + 1
 12                 );
 13    return l_rc;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test('MANAGER,CLERK') from dual;

F_TEST('MANAGER,CLER
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           1000
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

7 rows selected.


SQL>
```